# Applying CSS styling based on different pages in React

Tags: javascript, css, react.js, modules, jsx

**Short Story**: I created this [website](https://skreweverything.tk/) last year in plain HTML, CSS, JS which I can't even remember how I wrote that and now I can't even edit the website without breaking it. So, I'm re-writing everything in a proper way using React.

---

So, I'm making a website using React ( I'm still learning ) and I got confused about using CSS with it.

I have a `TW` component for type-writing animation like on the [home](https://skreweverything.tk/index.html) and [projects](https://skreweverything.tk/Projects.html) page.

You can see that same animation has different styles in [home](https://skreweverything.tk/) and [projects](https://skreweverything.tk/Projects.html) page.

Previously, I have just used different CSS rules present in different webpages( with code redundant ). But doing same in React is not possible because of it's component approach.

**Code**:

`typewriter.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { ICH } from '../individual-char-highlight/individual-char-highlight'; // When the mouse is hovered over a char it changes color
import b from '../css/blink.css'; // For cursor blinking effect
import s from './typewriter.css'; // Default style for this component



/**
 * By default, it returns a component which produces typewriter animation on the array of strings passed as `this.props.data`
 * *************************
 * *************************
 * Description of props:
 *
 * "Needed props"
 * name: `this.props.data[]`, type: Array(String)-> Produces typewriter animation on the array of strings passed
 * *************************
 * "Optional props"
 * name: `this.props.time`, type: Integer, default: 60 -> Milliseconds to delete or add one character to the screen
 *
 * name: `this.props.passTo`, type: String, default: undefined -> Used to pass the data to specified component after final string is constructed before it is displayed.
 */
export class TW extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // Initial state
        this.state = {
            data: ''
        };

        // - Mark methods
        this.animate = this.animate.bind(this);
        this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
        this.passTo = this.passTo.bind(this);
        this.animate();

    }

    /**
     * animate - Typing Animation logic
     *
     */
    animate() {

        var dataIndex = 0; // It is used to iterate the `this.props.data`
        var d = this.props.data[dataIndex]; // Current string to apply animation
        var strLength = d.length; // Length of current string
        var text = this.props.data; // It is the string that changes to produce type writer effect
        var flag = true; // It is used to add or remove the character from `text`
        var index = strLength; // It is used in `substr` to specify the `to` argument and from is always `0`
        var count = 0; // It is used to delay the adding of first character when `text` is empty.

        setInterval(function () {

            if (text.length == 0) // If the string `text` is empty
            {
                if(count == 15) // Initially `0` waits till it gets to `15` and then adds the char
                {
                    dataIndex = (dataIndex >= this.props.data.length - 1) ? 0 : ++dataIndex;
                    d = this.props.data[dataIndex]; // Update the string to apply animation on
                    strLength = d.length; // Update the length of current string
                    index = 1; // Increment `index` to add the 1st char
                    flag = true; // Make it true so it adds chars one-by-one in next `else if`
                    count = 0; // Again make it `0` for next iteration

                }
                else
                {
                    count++; // Increment `count` when `text` is empty untill `count` = `15`
                }

            }
            else if (strLength + 20 == index) // same like `count`, `+20` delays the deletion after the `text` is full
            {
                index--; // Decrement `index` to delete the last char.
                flag = false; // Make it `false` so it delets chars one-by-one in next `else if`
            }
            else if (flag) // It executes to add the chars to `text` one-by-one
            {
                index++;
            }
            else if (!flag)  // It executes to delete the chars from `text` one-by-one
            {
                index--;
            }

            text = d.substr(0, index) // Display the string, even if it's empty
            this.updateState(text); // Call to update the `this.state.data`

        }.bind(this), this.props.time); // Change this number to change the typing speed. Less = Fast
    }

    /**
     * updateState - Updates the state with current `text` to call the render.
     *
     * @param  {String} text Displays the constructed `text` string
     *
     */
    updateState(text){

      this.setState({ // Display the constructed `text` string
          data: text,
      });
    }


    /**
     * passTo - Sends the constructed string to another component for further components if specified any. Otherwise returns unmodified string as component
     *
     * @return {span}  Span which might be modified by other components or not
     */
    passTo(){

      let mainData;
      // `style` is used to position the component at the center approximately due to cursor(which shifts to left)
      // //`style` is used for cursor span to position the cursor according to the `this.props.data`
      if(this.props.passTo == 'ICH'){
        mainData = [
                        <span className={s['data']}  style={{position:'relative',left:'5%'}}><ICH data = {this.state.data} name="typewriter" /></span>,
                        <span className={b['blink'] + ' ' + s['cursor']} style={{position:'relative',left:'5%'}}>&#9614;</span>
                   ]
      }
      else {
        mainData = [
                        <span className={s['data']}>{this.state.data}</span>,
                        <span className={b['blink'] + ' ' + s['cursor']}>&#9614;</span>
                   ]
      }

      return mainData;
    }

    render() {

      let displayData = this.passTo(); // Final span to be displayed after all the modifications

        return (
                <span>{displayData}</span>
        );
    }
}

/**
 * Default value of `this.props.time` is 60 milliseconds
 * @type {Object}
 */
TW.defaultProps = {time: 60};
```

Now I want to apply a style based on the webpage where it is used.

---

I thought of two options.

**1)** As you can see above, I'm using `passTo()` and `this.props.passTo` to send the data to another component for further animation. Similarly, I can send a `style` object from parent component as `props` and use the same above logic to apply the `style` as in-line using conditional statements.

**2)** Doing similar to option 1 but instead of passing `style` object, adding the styles in `typewriter.css`(which has default styles for this component) with `className` as the webpage name and applying it.

Which one is better? And is there a way to apply CSS from parent component?

Thank you!